# Getting name/decemals of unstandardized token on Ethereum blockchain with web3.js

Tags: web3js, erc-20, etherscan

I understand how to call methods of name/symbol or decemals on ERC-20 tokens but what about tokens that do not have such.. for example this token here https://etherscan.io/token/0xE0B7927c4aF23765Cb51314A0E0521A9645F0E2A#readContract

All I see is totalSupply,balanceOf, owner,locked etc, but no symbol or any informative data..
Is it possible at all ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, some early tokens did not comply the standard when they were deployed. In particularly, `name`, `symbol` and `decimals` might be either spelled differently (e.g., `Decimals` or `DECIMALS`), or even missing altogether. In other cases, they do not conform to the type specified by the standard, for example, `bytes32 symbol` instead of `string symbol`.

Comment: In a somewhat worse scenario, some tokens did not comply with the standard of functions `approve`, `transfer` and `transferFrom` returning a `bool` value.